# Multiple counts for each ID

Tags: sql, t-sql, count

I'm trying to get my head around this, but unfortunately neither of my approaches works:

- I need a table with 3 columns:

  1. ItemID
  2. Number cases where ItemID has CostcentreID x
  3. Number cases where ItemID has CostcentreID y

`SELECT ItemID, Count1, Count2
FROM Table`

Output should be like:

### --ItemID--Count1--Count2

```
1       12      5
2        3      2
```

What i get when using

`SELECT ItemdID, SUM(case when costc...),...
 FROM Table`

is:

### --ItemID--Count1--Count2

```
1       12      0
2        3      0
```

due to the GROUP BY statement.

Anyway to solve this without a Cursor?

Also, a JOIN of 5 tables is needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its hard to debug your sql when you leave it completely out of the question.  Additionally, if you want to suss out a 5 table join, we need to see the schema.  Making a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) is often very helpful to communicate your problems.

Comment: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: Tip: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need with the joins, but here is the first part.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(ItemID INT, CostCentreID CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES  (1,'X'),
        (1,'X'),
        (1,'Y'),
        (2,'X'),
        (2,'Y'),
        (2,'Y'),
        (2,'Y');

SELECT  ItemID,
        SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN CostCentreID = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0
                END
            ) AS CostCentreX,
        SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN CostCentreID = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0
                END
            ) AS CostCentreY
FROM @table
GROUP BY ItemID
```

Results:

```
ItemID      CostCentreX CostCentreY
----------- ----------- -----------
1           2           1
2           1           3
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried that but it didn't seem to work. I tried again with another database and it worked.

Comment: Might have been because there was nothing that fit the condition in the database where it should. Thanks for the help!  :< Sorry, this was my first post, i'll take your advice and make myself more clear next time.

Comment: It's fine and don't let people over-complicate what a good question is. First make sure no one has answered your question and then have your question include these three things. 

1. A simple explanation of your data and your end goal. 

2. Sample data and your desired results from the sample data. 

3.What you've tried (normally your just your SQL script).